In Maxwell’s Fluid Analogy, is the Magnetic Field the “Wake”?
Does Maxwell's analogy of incompressible fluids extend so far that the magnetic part of a wave created by a moving electric charge is like the "wake" of a moving body through fluids? What is it about nature that determines the resulting perpendicular magnetic force, per the Lorentz force law, shown by a compass next to a current carrying wire, rotates clockwise to the moving charge when viewed from the direction of the current?


Does Maxwell's analogy of incompressible fluids extend so far that the
magnetic part of a wave created by a moving electric charge is like
the "wake" of a moving body through fluids

The wave (wake) of a body moving through a fluid is a pressure (scalar) longitudinal wave, but a magnetic field is a transverse vector wave.
Let $\mathbf{w}(t)$ be the location of a moving electric charge, $\mathbf{v}(t) = \dot{\mathbf{w}}(t)$ the velocity of the point charge, and $\mathbf{a}(t)$ the acceleration of the point charge.
The electric field created by a moving point charge is
$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t) = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{ R}{(\mathbf{R \cdot u})^3}\left[(c^2 -v^2)\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{R} \times (\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{a}) \right]$$
and the magnetic field is
$$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t)=\frac{1}{c} \hat{\mathbf{R}} \times \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)$$
where $$\mathbf{R} \equiv \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{w}(t_r)$$ and
$$\mathbf{u} \equiv c \hat{\mathbf{R}} - \mathbf{v}.$$
Note that these are evaluated at the retarded time determined by
$$R=|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{w}(t_r)| =c(t-t_r)$$
If you want to compare this to the wake generated by a particle moving in a fluid you need the equation for that. To my knowledge, the wake in a fluid is primarily determined by the cross-sectional area of the moving object, so I do not think it will be directly comparable.

only instantaneous?

As can be seen from above, the magnetic field is determined by the relative location and velocity of the point charge at the retarded time, so it is not instantaneous. Electromagnetic "news" travels at the speed of light.

What is it about nature that determines the resulting perpendicular
magnetic force, per the Lorentz force law, rotates counterclockwise to
the moving charge?

The Lorentz force law
$$\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$$
might seem like it has a preferred direction because of the cross product, but you have to remember the magnetic field itself depended on a cross product. (In the Biot savart law, it is the cross product term with the current and position). In the above example, we would have
$$\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{v} \times \left( \frac{1}{c} \hat{\mathbf{R}} \times \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)\right) = \frac{q}{c} \left(\hat{\mathbf{R}}(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{E}) - \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{v} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{R}}) \right)$$
The cross product term in the electric field can be similarly expanded:
$$\mathbf{R} \times (\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{a}) = \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{R} \cdot \mathbf{a}) - \mathbf{a}(\mathbf{R} \cdot \mathbf{u})$$

Edit to add:
All that we observe are forces on particles due to currents. Ignoring the complications in the non-time-steady case, fhe force on a particle due to a current is, from the Biot-Savart law:
$$\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B} = q\mathbf{v} \times \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}I 
\int \frac{\mathbf{I} \times \hat{\mathbf{R}}}{R^2}dl'$$
$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{q \mu_0}{4\pi}I \int \frac{ \mathbf{v} \times (\mathbf{I} \times \hat{\mathbf{R}})}{R^2}dl'=\frac{q \mu_0}{4\pi}I \int \frac{ \mathbf{I}( \mathbf{v} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{R}})-\hat{\mathbf{R}}(\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{I} )}{R^2}dl'$$

You clarified the first part, thank you for that. My follow-up is this. Even with Biot-Savart law considered, what property, motion or particle is it that gives rise to, and allows laws like Biot-Savart, the ‘right-hand-rule’, and Lorentz force law to exist in the first place? Why do the resulting field lines always point in the same direction to a moving current? What about our physical universe is it that tells the field around a moving charge to “always point your field lines clockwise, never counterclockwise, in reference to the charge’s direction.”

@Teragreg The second part of my post deals precisely with this concern. The expressions I showed at the bottom have no “handedness”

You could use a left handed convention for the cross product, and the physics would not change.

I didn’t mean to focus on handedess, but the direction of the field lines. Why is it that a compass needle always points north in the clockwise direction when placed near a current carrying wire? Asked differently, which mechanism of the universe determines that it’s always this direction? Even when applying Biot-Savart law, it always seems taken for granted that the field lines point north in the clockwise direction. Is this one of those things where “that’s just how the universe works”? Or is there a known physical mechanism that determines this direction? Thank you for your help.

@Teragreg The point being made is that the direction of the field lines is not physically observable. So the direction does not have any physical meaning. If you used a left-handed convention for cross products, which would be perfectly valid to do, the field lines would be pointing the other way. A compass points North because of a force.

The magnetic field is just a useful mathematical tool. All that is actually observed are forces on particles. The forces are determined by currents. The force relationship between a particle and a current has no handedness and no sense of clockwise or counterclockwise.

It seems to me like it’s an axiom found from observation and self-evidence that the direction of magnetic force always appears clockwise, not counterclockwise, when viewed from the perspective of the direction of current. But, I believe, we cannot say for sure why the direction is the way it is, all we can do is build laws and mathematical proofs that include that this is the case, then calculate the strength of the force at points and over time and take the direction of the force as a given, built into the axioms of the mathematical laws.

@Teragreg That is incorrect. It is not true that the force appears clockwise from the perspective of the current. It is true that using the right-hand-rule convention the force appears clockwise from the perspective of the magnetic field. Again, look at the last equation I wrote. The force is not appearing clockwise from anything.

Ok Ive been thinking I’m wrong, but just trying to understand how. And I appreciate your help greatly. I must be conflating these two concepts. It is my understanding that a compass needle will always point clockwise when viewed from the direction of current when placed near a current carrying wire, showing the direction of force. This is a universal truth. Since you’ve showed that the last equation does not say the force appears clockwise to anything, it leaves me with the question, what math does explain it? Why does a compass always point in that direction, not the other?

@Teragreg You should be asking a more basic question: why does a compass needle move at all? A compass needle is magnetized, which essentially means that there are electrons moving around in circles about the axis of the needle. The direction these electrons are already moving determines which way the compass needle will point. So, the compass needle will point clockwise because the electrons were already spinning clockwise, is a rough gist of it.

It is actually quite analogous to the phenomenon of gyroscopic precession. You can look up videos of this if you have not seen this before.
